# uwp set interval selectable hours

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I was wondering if it was possible to set an interval of time possible to select in a TimePicker control. For example between 12am and 1:30 p.m.

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Comment: you can use two time pickers exactly like the Calendar app in windows 10 a single time picker for showing time range is not yet supported in the UWP platform I am not sure if they even plan to add it as the use case scenarios are really less

Answer (score 0):

There is no single native control for this and lots of apps do it in different ways.
Common solutions are using two time pickers and adding your own logic to verify the range, a custom control, or using something like the [rangeselector](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit/controls/rangeselector).
What's best will depend on the precise requirements of your app.